# Best way to recruit testers for a remote usability test in the UK and France

Tags: usability-testing, recruitment

I need to recruit participants for a quick remote usability website test in the UK and in France. So far we tried facebook ads and classifieds. Do you have any suggestions where I can find participants, something that works well from your experience?

Comment: Sorry man, but this seems like an off topic question, where it can spark opinionated answers as apposed to definitive answers.

Comment: You might want to refer to this question for general approaches for recruiting testers. http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16409/how-to-recruit-user-test-participants

Answer (score 1):

you can try Mturk.com and specify the Country requirements.
Also talk to UserTesting.com they may be able to filter people to you.