# Any suggested communities to get survey responses on a volunteer basis?

Tags: surveys, user-feedback

I've used different reddit communities where people involved in these subreddits have a higher interest in the topics our product is centred around. But of course, that isn't always well received. Any other suggestions for similar communities?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recruit user test participants?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16409/how-to-recruit-user-test-participants)

Comment: Thanks Nash. It helps, but doesn't really help define possible communities that I'm just not thinking of (example, reddit, facebook, etc)

Comment: Have you tried asking the Redditors where else they hang out? Without knowing the topics of your product, it's hard to recommend other communities.